# plotting scatter3 and surf plots from loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot `scatter3` and `surf` plots from a loop. Below is my code but it isn't working...not sure where I'm going wrong but clearly something is wrong with the `z` matrix?

```
for e = 1:10; 
    x = rand(1,3);
    y = rand(1,3);
    A = x+y;

subplot(2,2,1)
p = find(A(:,1) > 1.1 & A(:,1) < 1.6);
Result = A(p,:);
scatter3(Result(:,1), Result(:,2), Result(:,3))
hold on

z(e,:) = [Result(1) Result(2) Result(3)];

end

subplot(2,2,2)
surf(z)
```

Comment: I got this error message when trying to run your code: `Attempted to access Result(1); index out of bounds because numel(Result)=0.`  This is because your `p` condition isn't satisfied - MATLAB could not find any elements in the first column that are between 1.1 and 1.6.  Therefore, when trying to plot the values, it is empty and you can't plot empty matrices!  I suggest you figure out what thresholds are more suitable because they seem rather adhoc.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng - but if the loop runs 10 times (or 100 times) then sometimes the conditions will be satisfied. So I want to store those results. If you take out the last line in the loop (z(e,:) = ...) then the scatter3 plot works. I think it is failing because p isn't satisfied but it isn't running 10 times?

Comment: Yes that's it. You still need to evaluate those boolean conditions because you'll have times when it is false.

Comment: @rayryeng - thanks, but sometimes I do want it to be false and I just want to plot the times it is true...

Comment: Sure.  I'll rewrite your code.  You definitely **do not** need a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reiterate what I said in my comment to you. I got this error message when trying to run your code: `Attempted to access Result(1); index out of bounds because numel(Result)=0`. This is because your `p` condition isn't satisfied - MATLAB could not find any elements in the first column that are between 1.1 and 1.6.

As such, what I would suggest you do is check to see if `Result` is empty before trying to access the value itself.  However, I would suggest you don't write a loop and generate all of the random values at once, then do the filtering with the Boolean conditions.  Therefore, the equivalent code without using a loop would be this:

```
x = rand(10,3);
y = rand(10,3);
A = x+y;
p = A(:,1) > 1.1 & A(:,1) < 1.6;
z = A(p,:);

figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
scatter3(z(:,1), z(:,2), z(:,3));
subplot(2,1,2);
surf(z);
```

We generate 10 3D points for `x` and `y` at the beginning, then add these and store this into `A`. Next, we find the rows in `A` that are between 1.1 and 1.6 in the first column and store this as a `logical` array.  We then use this array to index into `A` and store the results into `z`.  This is the recommended approach if you want to extract certain elements into an array rather than using `find`.

Once we obtain `z`, we plot these points with `scatter`, then also find a surface plot with `surf` for the same matrix.  BTW, I've fixed your `subplot` as you are only creating two plots, yet you are allocating space for 4 plots.

---

If you're absolutely bent on using your code, you would simply do this:

```
z = []; %// Change
for e = 1:10
    x = rand(1,3);
    y = rand(1,3);
    A = x+y;

    subplot(2,1,1)
    p = find(A(:,1) > 1.1 & A(:,1) < 1.6);
    Result = A(p,:);
    scatter3(Result(:,1), Result(:,2), Result(:,3))
    hold on

    if ~isempty(Result) %// Change here
        z = [z; Result(1) Result(2) Result(3)]; %// Change
    end

end

subplot(2,1,2)
surf(z)
```

What's important is the initialization of `z`.  I made this empty, and we only add to `z` **if `Result` is not empty** - this will happen if you generate a number that is not between 1.1 and 1.6.